# ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str' create table

Tags: python

I keep get the same error message for my code:

```
Associate       Business            Budget ($)          Setup Fee ($)       Mgmt Fee ($)        Annual Revenue ($)  Commission ($)      .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Group10Asg03.py", line 50, in <module>
    printResults(salesassociateList)
  File "/Users/Group10Asg03.py", line 30, in <module>
    print("{0:16}{1:20}{2:<20.2f}{3:<20.2f}{4:<20.2f}{5:<20.2f}{6:<20.2f}.".format(row[0], row[1], float(row[2]), float(row[3]), float(row[4]), float(row[5]), float(row[6])))
builtins.ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

I have tried multiple ways to fix, but it won't work. I need the code to show a table.

```
def printResults(salesassociateList):
    """ This function displays the results for each data in the salesassociateList, it displays all seven variables"""   
            
    total_f = total_tar = total_c = 0
    
    print("*********\n\nThe Results of Total Revenue and Commission Calculations\n\n*********")
    print("{0:16}{1:20}{2:20}{3:20}{4:20}{5:20}{6:20}.".format("Associate", "Business", "Budget ($)", "Setup Fee ($)", "Mgmt Fee ($)", "Annual Revenue ($)", "Commission ($)"))
    for row in salesassociateList:
        print("{0:16}{1:20}{2:<20.2f}{3:<20.2f}{4:<20.2f}{5:<20.2f}{6:<20.2f}.".format(row[0], row[1], float(row[2]), float(row[3]), float(row[4]), float(row[5]), float(row[6])))
        total_f += row[4] 
        total_tar += row[5] 
        total_c += row[6] 
        print("\nThe total monthly management fee is ${4:.2f}. The total annual revenue from all projects is ${5:.2f} and the total commission to all sales associates is ${6:.2f}.".format(total_f, total_tar, total_c))
```

Comment: you're trying to float-format and you don't have floats

Comment: `row[1]` is str, format is `{1:<20.1f}` for float, That's pretty clear

Comment: Your second placeholder uses `f`, but the second *argument* to `format` is not being converted to `float`. I'm guessing each row is a sequence of strings, so failing to convert means you're trying to do `float` formatting for a `str`.